# SQL Update Statement Does Nothing

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, hierarchy

I have a SQL `Update` statement that when run in VS2010 via the new query window works, but when I structure it as an update statement nothing happens.

I was wondering if someone can see what I'm doing wrong? Like I said the code works when executed via the query window in VS2010.

Here's my code:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(DBConnection.GetConnection().ConnectionString);

string updateStatement = 
    "DECLARE @OldParent hierarchyid, @NewParent hierarchyid " +

    "SELECT @OldParent = Hierarchy FROM SpecProducts " +
    "WHERE ID = @NodeToMoveID ; ------ top item to be moved " +

    "SELECT @NewParent = Hierarchy FROM SpecProducts " +
    "WHERE ID = @NodeToMoveIntoID  ; -- ID of item to move into - new parent " +

    "DECLARE children_cursor CURSOR FOR " +
    "SELECT Hierarchy FROM SpecProducts " +
    "WHERE Hierarchy = @OldParent; " +

    "DECLARE @ChildId hierarchyid; " +
    "OPEN children_cursor " +

    "FETCH NEXT FROM children_cursor INTO @ChildId; " +

    "WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 " +
    "BEGIN " +
    "START: " +

       "DECLARE @NewId hierarchyid; " +
       "SELECT @NewId = @NewParent.GetDescendant(MAX(Hierarchy), NULL) " +
       "FROM SpecProducts WHERE Hierarchy.GetAncestor(1) = @NewParent; " +

       "UPDATE SpecProducts " +
       "SET Hierarchy = Hierarchy.GetReparentedValue(@ChildId, @NewId), " +
           "MovedToDate = @MovedToDate, " +
           "MovedToBy = @MovedToBy " +
       "WHERE Hierarchy.IsDescendantOf(@ChildId) = 1; " +

       "IF @@error <> 0 GOTO START -- On error, retry " +
       "FETCH NEXT FROM children_cursor INTO @ChildId; " +
       "END " +

       "CLOSE children_cursor; " +
       "DEALLOCATE children_cursor;";

SqlCommand updateCommand = new SqlCommand(updateStatement, connection);
updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NodeToMoveID", nodeIDToMove);
updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NodeToMoveIntoID", newParentID);
updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MovedToDate", DateTime.Now);
updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MovedToBy", userModifying.ID);

try
{
    connection.Open();
    updateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

    return true;
}
```

One thing to point out is that when my code executes in VS2010 Query window, I get a warning about the 'Declare' feature, but I press continue and it works. Does my statement not working have anything to do with the Declare features?

Any thoughts/solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks.

Rob

Comment: Side-note: you should **close** your connection right after executing the query...

Comment: Instead of hard coding these sql statements, why don't you turn it into a stored procedure?

Comment: If you put a break point at `SqlCommand updateCommand = new SqlCommand(updateStatement, connection);` and get the value of `updateStatement`, run this in the query window, this works?

Comment: Is any type of exception thrown or does it go through the query without a problem? Also, see what the `int` returned from `updateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()` is, as it may assist in understanding what is happening.

Comment: Hi folks. Thanks for replying to my post.

@marc_s Sorry I didn't copy all of my code, only the bit I thought was necessary. There is a connection close and catch after the code I supplied.

Comment: @unlimit I haven't tried a stored procedure yet. It's something I will look into in the future.

Thanks again all of you. Any more advice is appreciated.

Comment: @danielu13 No exception is thrown, thus why I'm a little confused about what's happening here.

Thanks again. Any more advice is appreciated.

Comment: @christiandev I will try your solution shortly.

Thanks again. Any more advice is appreciated.

Comment: @danielu13 the returned int is -1. When the same code executes in the VS2010 Query Window I get 5.

Comment: This is the article my code came from [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677256.aspx)

Comment: hmmm... I've just tried the code again in VS2010 Query and I get the following exceptions.

**Error source:** .net.sqlclient data provider
**Error message:** Must declare the scalar variabe NodeToMoveID & NodeToMoveIntoID & MovedToDate. - Usually VS pops open a window where I can define the variables. If I replace the (at) variables with hard coded values then it works fine.

Comment: Looking at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx), `ExecuteNonQuery` returns -1 when a database rollback occurs. This rollback is probably because of that error. Maybe just add those variables into the statement rather than using SQL variables?

Comment: Ah yes that's an idea thanks @danielu13. The problem is with the variables being added as parameters. I guess your solution to add them as text strings is one way around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am adding this as an answer since the comment discussion was getting a bit long.

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx), `ExecuteNonQuery` returns -1 when there is a database rollback. This is likely related to the error you gave:

> **Error source:** .net.sqlclient data provider 
>   **Error message:** Must declare the scalar variabe NodeToMoveID & NodeToMoveIntoID & MovedToDate.

As you mentioned, you were having issues using the SQL parameters. One solution to this is to replace those parameters with variables in `updateStatement`.

Another thing you could try is using a stored procedure and changing those parameters, although that may not work for some reason either.